# how to use # in linux shell script

Tags: shell

I know that using # in a shell script will comment the rest of the line.

I have to pass a variable to a shell script from another file. I am using "export" to do this. The problem is that the value of the variable has a # in it, and so I am not able to get the value in my shell script.

The script I am using is given below

export FILE_NAME=#gclfac*sched$

As you can see the # is in the beginning of the value I am not able to get anything in my shell script.

How can I pass a'#' value in shell script without commenting out the rest of the line? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Using a `#` will not necessarily comment the rest of the line.  Consider `echo foo#bar`.  The rules are complicated but can roughly be summarized as: `#` designates a comment only if it is unquoted and preceded by whitespace, a semi-colon, or a pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
export FILE_NAME='#gclfac*sched$'
```

or

```
export FILE_NAME="#gclfac*sched$"
```

script to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
export FILE_NAME='#jfkslj**23948290$'
echo $FILE_NAME "_ $FILE_NAME"
```

put it to test.sh make it executable (`chmod +x test.sh`) and run as `./test.sh` and post the output here.
ps. Is your shell `bash` (if not, change she-bang [#!/bin/bash at the first string] to your shell and don't forget to write us about it)?

Comment: @user1538033 please follow the instructions I've added to my answer. We'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Place your assignment string in double-quotes. So to use your example it would be;

```
FILE_NAME="#gclfac*sched$"
export FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Sorry @user1538033 I forgot a line-break... I did this in haste earlier. I've edited my original answer above.